# How can I put in a form where user-uploaded files are parsed and then displayed on a new url?

Tags: python, file-upload, url-routing, pyramid

Ultimately, I want it so that when users upload a file, it parses the file and then creates a new url (using `save_url`) where it displays the output of that parsing.

Here is the edit.pt that renders the form:

```
<form action="/add_page" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="stl">Stl</label>
<input name="stl" type="file" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Here is the `add_page` section of `views.py`:

```
@view_config(route_name='add_page', renderer='templates/edit.pt')
def add_page(request):
    input_file=request.POST['stl'].file
    i1, i2 = itertools.tee(input_file)
    vertices = [map(float, line.split()[1:4])
                for line in i1
                if line.lstrip().startswith('vertex')]

    normals = [map(float, line.split()[2:5])
                for line in i2
                if line.lstrip().startswith('facet')]

    ordering=[]
    N=len(normals)

    ...(parsing data)...


    return data
    if data is None:
        displayNotification['please upload file']
    if 'stl' in request.params:
        name=request.params('name')
        page=Page(name,data)
        return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('view_page',pagename=name))
    save_url=request.route_url('add_page',pagename=name)
    page=Page('','')
    return dict(page=page,save_url=save_url)
```

And when I try and go to `http://localhost:6543/add_page/new` (to add a new page with a new url), I get this error:

```
KeyError: "No key 'stl': Not a form request".
```

This error occurs on the line under `def add_page(request):`. I am formatting it like so as to go off of [this tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/forms/file_uploads.html).

Comment: Please do include *full* tracebacks so we do not have to guess where things might be wrong.

Comment: are you referring to my other open question or the ...(parsing data)... part. I have realized that my two questions are much more similar than I thought. Is there a way to merge them?

Comment: Not really; you can request to close this one as a duplicate of the other one (flag for mod attention, choose other, explain with a link to the other question).

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two scenarios of "what to do after you saved data on form submit":

1. you save the data (say, the result of the file parsing) to some permanent storage (database, which will give you some unique URI to address that file (say, `/files/123123`). Then you just issue an HTTP redirect to that location:

   ```
   @view_config(renderer="templates/form_view.pt")
   def form_view(self):

       if self.request.method == 'POST':
           if _validation_passed(request):
               new_url = _save_data(request)
               return HTTPFound(new_url)
           else:
               return _render_form(values=request.POST, msg="Validation failed")

       # We are a GET not a POST, render empty form
       return _render_form()
   ```

The new "page" stays permanently, so if you just visit `/files/123123` in your browser you'll see the same page.

1. Alternatively, your view receives an HTTP post, does something with the data and, instead of redirecting to another view, just returns a blob of HTML just like any other "normal" view. This is used when, say, the form fails validation and you want to re-display the form, but is also useful when you do not save the data anywhere, so basically you don't have an URI to redirect to.

   ```
   @view_config(renderer="templates/form_view.pt")
   def form_view(self):

       if self.request.method == 'POST':
           if _validation_passed(request):
               return _render_data(request)
           else:
               return _render_form(values=request.POST, msg="Validation failed")

       # We are a GET not a POST, render empty form
       return _render_form()
   ```

In this case, the result page will only be visible after the file is submitted, to view it again the user will need to re-upload the file.

Just follow one of those patterns and you'll be able to sort the things out.

There is an additional complication with file submits - you generally can't re-display the form with the file field populated without doing some trickery with storing a file in a temporary location on the server.